# How to include all PIDs in tab completion?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

When I enter a command that takes a process ID (such as `kill` and `strace -p`), ZSH's tab completion offers what looks like the PIDs of the processes running in my current shell session. How can I make it offer the PIDs of all running processes instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will depend on the exact flavour of `ps` involved, but may run something along the lines of

```
zstyle ':completion:*:processes' command 'ps -A'
```